# Angular Firestore problem to retrieve data with "collectionData" @angular/fire/firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm not an expert of Angular but why I'm able to use "collectionData" (from @angular/fire/firestore) to retrive all data from Cloud Firestore with this configuration in Angular?

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___ 
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | | 
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | | 
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 15.0.2
Node: 18.12.1
Package Manager: npm 9.6.7
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 15.0.2
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1500.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular   15.0.2
@angular-devkit/core            15.0.2
@angular-devkit/schematics      15.0.2
@angular/cdk                    15.0.0
@angular/fire                   7.6.1
@angular/material               15.0.0
@schematics/angular             15.0.2
rxjs                            7.5.7
typescript                      4.8.4
```

meanwhile I'm not able with this configuration

```
/ \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | | 
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | | 
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 15.2.0
Node: 18.12.1
Package Manager: npm 9.6.7
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 16.2.6
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms     
... localize, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------       
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1602.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular   16.2.3
@angular-devkit/core            16.2.3
@angular-devkit/schematics      16.2.3
@angular/cli                    15.2.0
@angular/fire                   7.6.1
@schematics/angular             16.2.3
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      5.1.6
```

this is my service:

```js
        import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Firestore, addDoc, collection, collectionData, doc, getDocs, query } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Place } from '../interfaces/place';
import { Observable, map } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PlaceService {

  constructor(private firestore: Firestore) { }

  addPlace(place: Place) {
    const placeRef = collection (this.firestore, 'places' );
    return addDoc (placeRef, place);
  }

  getPlaces(): Observable<Place[]> {
    const placeRef = collection(this.firestore, 'places');
    return collectionData(placeRef, {idField: 'id'}) as Observable<Place[]>;

 }

}
```

and my component:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Place } from 'src/app/interfaces/place';
import { PlaceService } from 'src/app/services/place.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-place',
  templateUrl: './list-place.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-place.component.css']
})
export class ListPlaceComponent implements OnInit {

  places: Place[] = [];

  constructor (private placeService: PlaceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.placeService.getPlaces().subscribe(res => {
      this.places = res
    });
  }

}
```

and the error when using "collectionData"

```html
ERROR FirebaseError: Expected type 'Query', but it was: a custom wh object
```

and package.json file:

```js
{
  "name": "pass-h-web-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.6.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.2.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^15.1.1",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "firebase": "^10.4.0",
    "jquery": "^3.7.1",
    "npm": "^10.1.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.2.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^16.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.1.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems you shared your component twice, instead of adding your service

Comment: Please share with us your PlaceService class and your package.json file.

Comment: I correct my post inserting PlaceService and package.json file. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I came across this ticket having the exact same problem description, unable to find an answer. When I tried changing package versions I ran into another problem that also was not easy to find an answer for. So I tried inspecting what relevant packages where defined as dependencies for `@angular/fire@7.6.0` (the version I'm using). These are `firebase@^9.8.2` and `rxfire@6.0.0`. So you need to have those versions, or newer, up to the ones that where available when `@angular/fire@7.6.0` was released (`firebase@^9.22.1` and `rxfire@6.0.3`).

Because `rxfire@6.0.3` is pretty old I kept that one and downgraded firebase to 9.8.2 and then my issue went away. Haven't tried upgrading the packages yet, but I'm sure I can bump the versions a bit...

Comment: Thanks Ruudt, but I downgraded firebase to 9.8.2 without success. Is there a best way to configure from scratch a project for firestore?

Comment: Can you list installed packages and versions? I'll compare with mine...

Comment: After some attempt (and many hours spent unsuccessfully) I solved with an update of firebase tool (npm install -g firebase-tools)